# Why does the following not appear to open an SQL connection?

Tags: php, windows, apache, http, web-deployment

I find that the folowing script hangs for some reason. It will load and PHP doesn't see any errors, but it will not process the data (noting that we are in a context where I have a seperate login database open.)

In process.php we have the following:

```
<? PHP
//Process the POST data in prepration to write to SQL database.
$_POST['chat_input'] = $input;   
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");    
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];   
$name = $_SESSION['username'];    
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "id3263427_chat_user";
$password = "Itudmenif1!Itudmenif1!";
$dbname = "id3263427_chat_user";
$id = "NULL";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($link === false){
   die("ERROR: Could not connect. " .  mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO `chat` (`id`, `username`, `ip`, `timestamp`,   
        `message`)  VALUES ('$id','$name', '$ip', '$time', '$input')';

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){ 
    mysqli_close($conn);
    header('Location: ../protected_page.php');
} else { 
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

?>
```

the html form passed to the script above is as follows:

```
<form action="/process.php" method="post" id="chat">
    <b> Send A Message (500 Character Max):</b><br>
    <textarea name="chat_input" form="chat" size="500"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value=submit>
</form>
```

Not sure what's going on with this.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this `$_POST['chat_input'] = $input;` and not this `$input = $_POST['chat_input'];`?

Comment: I corrected that point, and it seemed to be of no consequence with whatever's going on.

Comment: are you sure there are no errors reported check your sql string it must be surrounded by double quote normally if you simple quote for column name

Comment: You're also using two differnet variable names for your connection, `$conn` and `$link`. Try chaning to `$link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`

Comment: Check the `display_errors` setting in your php.ini. This is off by default very often but should be on in a development environment.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I'm using a host, I'm not able to modify the php.ini file- the hosting service locks it down.

Comment: OK I corrected the problem pamahomme pointed out. I also confirmed that PHP will throw errors if any exist. Running the revised version of the script, we get a whitepage in the browser, and no data writes to SQL. I was also able to confirm that PHP Will throw errors by running a test script with errors.

Comment: You'll need to remove the space here `<? PHP` and in my opinion go with lowercase `<?php`

Comment: Yep that did it. Now i get this: syntax error, unexpected '$id' (T_VARIABLE) in /storage/ssd4/427/3263427/public_html/process.php on line 18

Answer (score 2):

You got the syntax error because you're closing the $sql string before $id with your `'`.

What is this about your $id variable? With your current code you will insert the String "NULL". If you want to set the sql value null you should use `$id = null;` or just don't insert any value.

If you want your database to set an id, also leave it blank.

```
$input = $_POST['chat_input'];
$id = null;

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($conn->connect_error){
  die("ERROR: Could not connect. " .  $conn->connect_error);
}
```

**First solution**

If this isn't a production code, you could insert the variables directly into the statement, but you should use `"` instead of `'` for your sql string, so you can insert variables and `'` without closing the string.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO chat (id, username, ip, timestamp, message) VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$ip', '$time', '$input')";
if($conn->query($sql) === true) {
 $conn->close();
 header('Location: ../protected_page.php');
} else {
 echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " .$conn->error;
 $conn->close();
}
```

**Second solution**

A better approach would be a prepared statement.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO chat (username, ip, timestamp, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $ip, $time, $input);

if($stmt->execute()) {
 $stmt->close();
 $conn->close();
 header('Location: ../protected_page.php');
} else {
 echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $stmt. " . $conn->error;
 $stmt->close();
 $conn->close();
}
```

The `"s"` in [`bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) defines a string at the given position, if you want to insert an integer, use `"i"` instead.

e.g. `bindParam("sis", $string, $integer, $string);`